# How can i listing current category and Featured Category post list?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories, functions, query-posts

I have a Featured Post Category. Im marked some post Featured. When i viewing a category page(e.g. Sport), i want to list on sidebar both marked post list (e.g Featured and Sport,)

I tryed with that following code.It's worked for me but when i using my code i see two category post (e.g Sport ), category post list affected by my code and listing same post list.

My example picture! [Here](http://www.screencast.com/t/8zglaK4nFV)

How can i fix that?
My Code:

```
<?php
//55 is my Featured Category id
if ( is_category() ) {
  $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
}
query_posts(array('category__and' => array(55, $current_cat )));

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>  </li>
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want one list to be "Sports" and the other list to be "Featured Post"?

Comment: I want to see that, When i view category page(e.g Sports),i want to see Featured and Sport(Current Category)post list on sidebar(widget). its worked with my code but my Sport post  list too  changing(Featured and Sports) i want to see it just on sidebar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about your custom secondary loop affecting your main loop, correct?

`query_posts()` alters the main loop. A quick fix would be to call `wp_reset_query()` after your custom loop to reset the query data:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

However, it's more efficient and friendlier to use `WP_Query()` instead of `query_posts()` (especially if you're making a secondary loop). This should be the equivalent of your provided code using `WP_Query()`:

```
<?php
if ( is_category() ) {
    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
}

$args = array(
    'category__and' => array( 55, $current_cat )
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

References:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: It's worked.. Many thanx @BigBagel